# Can't disable v-edit-dialog in Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this `v-edit-dialog` below and even when the editMode is false the dialog box pops up!

I've also tried just setting the property to disabled like

```
:disabled="!editMode" => disabled
```

and it still pops up!

```html
<v-edit-dialog :return-value.sync="props.item.productAnnotationText" large lazy persistent :disabled="!editMode" @save="inputAnnotation(props.item.productAnnotationText, props.item.id)">
  <div>{{ props.item.productAnnotationText }}</div>
  <div slot="input" class="mt-2 title">Update Annotation</div>
  <v-text-field slot="input" v-model="props.item.productAnnotationText" label="Edit" single-line counter maxlength="50" autofocus :disabled="!editMode" color="#1976d2"></v-text-field>
</v-edit-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
v-if="editMode"
```

Then it will 'go away' if edit mode it false.

or

Bind it to editMode.  The `value` of v-model controls the visibility.

```
v-model='editMode'
```

Using v-model will also set editMode to false if the user closes the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The v-edit-dialog component doesn't have a 'disabled' prop so there is no way to stop it popping up if clicked. The only real option is to make the v-text-field disabled, as you already have, but this won't stop the dialog opening.

Apparently the vuetify team aren't fans of it.

> There's a possibility that edit dialog will be removed in 2.0, so it's
>   not going to get much love

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm late for the party.

I wrapped v-edit-dialog with a div, with v-show .

```
<div v-show="editarRules">
  <v-edit-dialog >
...
  </v-edit-dialog>
</div>
```

and I have another div with the value I want t show, and the opposite condition in v-show.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about some CSS?

Have a container with some class: "`some-class`".

Toggle the class like so: `:class="'some-class': !editMode"`

And then in CSS disable activating the edit dialog with: `.some-class .v-small-dialog__activator { pointer-events: none; }`